# how to set background animation of some icons moving from bottom to top in wordpress website .?

Tags: html, wordpress, css-animations, elementor

i have some svg's of icon that i want to show them moving from bottom to top like [this](https://codepen.io/Mark_Bowley/pen/PozwyP)in the hero section of  elementor. How can i achieve it in wordpress website .
i'm having hard time , while creating this animation using css. I've search on internet to get some example code , that is using icons for animations in the background , but all of them were using shapes.

```css
body {
    background: #00b4ff;
    color: #333;
    font: 100% Lato, Arial, Sans Serif;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#background-wrap {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

/* KEYFRAMES */

@-webkit-keyframes animateBubble {
    0% {
        margin-top: 1000px;
    }
    100% {
        margin-top: -100%;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes animateBubble {
    0% {
        margin-top: 1000px;
    }
    100% {
        margin-top: -100%;
    }
}

@keyframes animateBubble {
    0% {
        margin-top: 1000px;
    }
    100% {
        margin-top: -100%;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes sideWays { 
    0% { 
        margin-left:0px;
    }
    100% { 
        margin-left:50px;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes sideWays { 
    0% { 
        margin-left:0px;
    }
    100% { 
        margin-left:50px;
    }
}

@keyframes sideWays { 
    0% { 
        margin-left:0px;
    }
    100% { 
        margin-left:50px;
    }
}

/* ANIMATIONS */

.x1 {
    -webkit-animation: animateBubble 5s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: animateBubble 25s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: animateBubble 25s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    
    left: -5%;
    top: 5%;
    
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
    transform: scale(0.6);
}

.x2 {
    -webkit-animation: animateBubble 20s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: animateBubble 20s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: animateBubble 20s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    
    left: 5%;
    top: 80%;
    
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.4);
    transform: scale(0.4);
}

.x3 {
    -webkit-animation: animateBubble 28s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: animateBubble 28s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: animateBubble 28s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    
    left: 10%;
    top: 40%;
    
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
}

.x4 {
    -webkit-animation: animateBubble 22s linear infinite, sideWays 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: animateBubble 22s linear infinite, sideWays 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: animateBubble 22s linear infinite, sideWays 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    
    left: 20%;
    top: 0;
    
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
    transform: scale(0.3);
}

.x5 {
    -webkit-animation: animateBubble 29s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: animateBubble 29s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: animateBubble 29s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    
    left: 30%;
    top: 50%;
    
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    transform: scale(0.5);
}

.x6 {
    -webkit-animation: animateBubble 21s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: animateBubble 21s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: animateBubble 21s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
}

.x7 {
    -webkit-animation: animateBubble 20s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: animateBubble 20s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: animateBubble 20s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    
    left: 65%;
    top: 70%;
    
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.4);
    transform: scale(0.4);
}

.x8 {
    -webkit-animation: animateBubble 22s linear infinite, sideWays 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: animateBubble 22s linear infinite, sideWays 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: animateBubble 22s linear infinite, sideWays 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    
    left: 80%;
    top: 10%;
    
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
    transform: scale(0.3);
}

.x9 {
    -webkit-animation: animateBubble 29s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: animateBubble 29s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: animateBubble 29s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    
    left: 90%;
    top: 50%;
    
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
    transform: scale(0.6);
}

.x10 {
    -webkit-animation: animateBubble 26s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: animateBubble 26s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: animateBubble 26s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    
    left: 80%;
    top: 80%;
    
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
    transform: scale(0.3);
}

/* OBJECTS */

.bubble {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0px 10px 30px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0px 10px 30px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    box-shadow: 0 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0px 10px 30px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}

.bubble:after {
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.5)), color-stop(70%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%); /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%); /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#80ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */

    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 20px 30px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 20px 30px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0 20px 30px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    
    content: "";
    height: 180px;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="background-wrap">
    <div class="bubble x1"></div>
    <div class="bubble x2"></div>
    <div class="bubble x3"></div>
    <div class="bubble x4"></div>
    <div class="bubble x5"></div>
    <div class="bubble x6"></div>
    <div class="bubble x7"></div>
    <div class="bubble x8"></div>
    <div class="bubble x9"></div>
    <div class="bubble x10"></div>
</div>
```